# HTML Canvas: mouse click hit test by using ghost canvas - anti-aliasing troubles

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm writing an JavaScript application that is drawing arbitrarily shaped objects on a HTML canvas. The user should be able to select any of the objects by clicking on them.

To make this an O(1) operation I'm using a shadow canvas, i.e. a not displayed canvas that has exactly the same size, where each object drawn on the normal canvas is also drawn there - but with a color that represents it's `ID`.
So a simple `ghostContex.getImageData()` together with the mouse click coordinates gives me the color at that pixel and thus the `ID` of the clicked object.

All of that is working fine - except when I click on the exact border of an object.

As it's drawn with anti-aliasing on the ghost canvas I get a wrong color (as that color is a mixture between the correct `ID` and the `ID` of the object under it that was drawn before...). This wrong color is representing a wrong `ID` and thus I'm selecting a totally different object :(

How can I solve that problem?

Note #1: I'm already using the translate(0.5, 0.5) trick to prevent most anti-aliasing
Note #2: I was trying to write this application with SVG before, but especially this object selection was extremely slow as I guess it's been too many objects for the collision detection. That's the main reason why I want a O(1) approach now... Oh, and this way I can easily draw a much bigger line on the ghost canvas than the line is drawn on the normal canvas to make picking much easier.
Note #3: Relevant browsers are Firefox, Chrome, Android 2.3+ native and iOS native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why I couldn't accept any answer here is quite easy and quite sad: it doesn't exist... :(

The antialiasing can not be switched of, the standard has no method for that. But the standard does have a hit test function (http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/2dcontext/html5_canvas_CR/#hit-regions) that would do exactly what is needed here. Even in a nice way that would hide the nasty details for the developer - but it's not implemented in any of the browsers right now.
And implementation was looking to be far away till impossible (see e.g. comment #6 at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=328961). But apparently it gained momentum during the last month...

So what can be done in the mean time? What did I do?

In my code I could implement for each shape a `isPointInShape()` method. So I use the ghost canvas trick to get a shape and verify with the `isPointInShape()` that I really selected the correct shape. This helps in the anti aliased pixels not to pick a wrong shape (just think of clicking on the border of shape #2 where we had a 50% antialias transparency - this would tell you wrongly a selection of shape #1...).

If implementing a generic `isPointInShape()` is quite hard for your shape you could try a trick that I was reading of somewhere else (I didn't try it tough, so I haven't tested it...):
Create an additional ghost canvas of size 1x1 pixel that is positioned exactly on the mouse position. Then draw the shape of interest - when the A of the RGBA is changed, this shape does belong to that pixel.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but recently I had a similar issue. The way I solved the "seam of two colors" problem was doing a 10x10 pixel sampling of the secondary canvas instead of a single pixel. I then stringified the RGB values and used these as keys in a map that mapped to the object that color represents. So initially with the 1 pixel sampling I used the map immediately to determine the associated object but antialiasing created halfway colors that didn't exist in the map. The 10x10 method solves this problem by looping through the 100 RGB values returned and creating a "counting map." This map uses the stringified colors and maps them to a count, but only includes valid colors from the first map in the count. So you end up with a map saying you counted 65 red pixels and 23 blue pixels (where the remaining 12 pixels were some weird anti-alias hybrid). In the same loop where I was counting the colors I also maintained a variable for current max count and current color associated with that max count (to avoid looping through this new map again). Now at the end you have the color that was counted the most in that 10x10 sampling and can use that to map back to the object associated with it. You will only get an undefined result if no valid colors were found in the 10x10 sample which you can reasonably assume means the "background" was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I made up the name ghost context! Are you using my old tutorial? :)

In that old tutorial I do not clear the ghost context after each object is drawn to it. In your case, to fix your issue, you may need to clear after testing each object on the ghost context.

Make sure of course that you are translating the ghost context and normal context by precisely the same amounts. (and translating them back, or resetting the transformation, afterwards).

Comment: At times I got frustrated with the slow SVG hit speed I can across the idea to use a hidden canvas (probably read it somewhere). That was quite a few months ago. As I restarted my efforts now and came implementing it across the anti-aliasing issues I researched the web of course - and there I stumbled upon you old tutorial. So I got (at least?) how to name it from there - thanks!